# Uppercase Lowercase SAMBA file creation

Tags: c#, .net, samba, uppercase, lowercase

Using the C# .Net 2 framework, is there any way to create two files differing only in uppercase/lowercase in a case-sensitive SAMBA drive?

For example:

myFile.txt
MyFile.txt

This is the SAMBA configuration:

```
smb.conf

    case sensitive = yes
    preserve case = yes
    short preserve case = yes
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: C# is case sensitive. Did you try? What happened?

Answer (score 1):

Is your client perhaps running Windows?

The "case insensitive" setting in Samba is only useful if the client supports case insensitive filename lookups. Windows does not, and it will have trouble if you have two files with the same name but a different case.

Clients that do support case insensitivity include the SMB support in the Linux kernel and Samba's own "smbclient".